# Is there shortcut key for toggle between dark/light mode in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there shortcut key for toggle between dark/light mode in chrome?

Switch between `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark/light)`

Comment: No, but you can open commands palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) when devtoolos is focused and type "emda" or "emli". There's also a quick menu in Elements inspector: https://puu.sh/JcSkJ/96efa7bd6a.png

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a keyboard shortcut, but a toggle in the **Styles** pane of the **Elements** tab is the closest you can get to quickly switch between a light/dark mode.

1. Open devtools > Inside the "Styles" pane, right next to the "+" button, click the Icon "Toggle common rendering emulations".
2. Choose the prefers-color-scheme option to emulate the corresponding color scheme.

More info:
https://www.canidev.tools/emulate-color-schemes/chrome

[image]

Comment: If you dont mind switching the entire OS level theme, then you can create a custom keyboard shortcut at the OS level to toggle between two themes.

Answer (score 1):

Coming soon in Chrome 105, you can add a keyboard shortcut for toggling dark/light themes in Chrome DevTools.

But first you need to enable the experiment to [enable editable keyboard shortcut](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-88/#keyboard-shortcuts)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Press **“Win + I”** keys to Windows Settings app and then navigate to **“Personalization”** section. Go to **“Colors”** section and select **“Dark”** option for **“Choose your default app mode”**.

Comment: No. I looking for shortcut key to toggle between modes in chrome.
Because I create css styles for dark mode and for light mode and each change I need to check in dark mode and light mode. and it's hard to do that with devtools.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).